# Power BI DAX: Group by Monthly Growth Rate

Tags: date, powerbi, dax

I got the following sample data:

```
Product Group   Product Monthly Start Date  Sales Qty
Mobile Phone A  Mobile Phone A-1    1/1/2021    100
Mobile Phone A  Mobile Phone A-1    2/1/2021    120
Mobile Phone B  Mobile Phone B-1    1/1/2021    90
Mobile Phone B  Mobile Phone B-1    2/1/2021    78
```

What I want is to calculate the Monthly product growth rate (below).

```
Product Group   Product Month Start Date    Growth Rate
Mobile Phone A  Mobile Phone A-1    1/1/2021    null
Mobile Phone A  Mobile Phone A-1    2/1/2021    20%
Mobile Phone B  Mobile Phone B-1    1/1/2021    null
Mobile Phone B  Mobile Phone B-1    2/1/2021    -13%
```

I guess I need to use groupby and sort order by the Month Start Date and calculate the rate.

Does anyone know the best way of calculating it?

Thanks.

Comment: Do you have a date table?  Also, you post title says group by monthly growth rate but your question asks how to calculate the weekly growth rate.  Please clarify what you are actually trying to do.

Comment: Hi Jenn,  I have a date table.Also sorry that it is monthly. Any clue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do it this way (assuming you are viewing the result with a monthly granularity):

Total Sales Qty = SUM( ExampleTable[Sales Qty] )

MTD Sales Qty =
TOTALMTD( [Total Sales Qty], Dates[Date] )

MTD Sales Qty LM =
CALCULATE( [MTD Sales Qty], DATEADD(Dates[Date], -1, MONTH ) )

MoM Sales Qty Change =
DIVIDE([MTD Sales Qty] - [MTD Sales Qty LM], [MTD Sales Qty LM], BLANK() )

Answer (score 1):

You would calculate month-over-month growth using a sequence of four measures:

1. sum of the column
2. amount for the prior month
3. change month-over-month
4. change month-over-month %

These DAX patterns can can be used to get you started.  Make sure you add the necessary columns to your date table, then modify the measures below with your date table, fact table column to be quantified and measures you create.

[DAX Patterns - Month Related Calculations](https://www.daxpatterns.com/month-related-calculations/)

Sum of the Fact Table Column

```
Sales Amount:= sum ( SalesTable[Sales Qty] )
```

Amount for Prior Month

```
Sales PM := 
VAR CurrentYearMonthNumber = SELECTEDVALUE ( 'Date'[Year Month Number] ) 
VAR PreviousYearMonthNumber = CurrentYearMonthNumber - 1 
VAR Result =
        CALCULATE (
            [Sales Amount],
            REMOVEFILTERS ( 'Date' ),
            'Date'[Year Month Number] = PreviousYearMonthNumber
        ) 
RETURN
    Result
```

Change Month-Over-Month

```
Sales MOM :=
VAR ValueCurrentPeriod = [Sales Amount]
VAR ValuePreviousPeriod = [Sales PM]
VAR Result =
    IF (
        NOT ISBLANK ( ValueCurrentPeriod ) && NOT ISBLANK ( ValuePreviousPeriod ),
        ValueCurrentPeriod - ValuePreviousPeriod
    )
RETURN
    Result
```

Change Month-Over-Month %

```
Sales MOM % :=
DIVIDE (
    [Sales MOM],
    [Sales PM]
)
```